# Is there a way to get the output of a bash script to "feed" into a variable in a python script that executes the action initially?

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, asus-xtion

So, I have a bash script that feeds out data from a sensor that is connected to the NVidea Jetson TK-1 in string format in the shell. Is there any way I can run a python script that initializes the bash script. Takes the output data in bash, feeds it back into a python string variable where it can be parsed? I cannot edit the bash script.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In python:

```
   import subprocess
   bash_output = subprocess.check_output('run bash script here')
```

Subprocess.check_output sends commands to the shell and the shell pipes the results back to python.  Look at examples of using and documentation on `subprocess.check_output` [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html).

Comment: Will this work when I can only run the bash script once and new data comes out every ~10ms?

Comment: Ah, no it will not.  subprocess.check_output waits for the process to finish.  Could you output from bash to a file and use python to poll for changes in the file?

Comment: I have no access to the bash script if that is what you mean

Comment: He means can you change from using the bash script to a python alternative.

Comment: I mean, can you run the bash script like "bash_script_name > bash_output.txt" and then while that is running, run a python program that opens and reads the contents of that file every second or something?

Comment: No, it is not possible. The output is from a sample application that I have no way to edit. I just need the output from the sample application which is printed on the console as a string. I just thought python was the way to go.

Comment: Could you `tee` the output? Or `tail -f` perhaps and Popen with a pipe to stdout, maybe?

Comment: I guess the text output could work but wouldn't it not be possible since both scripts would need to be running at the same time?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with 'tee' or 'tail -f' I'm not familiar with the function of those